# Setting SwiftUI View as NSMenuBarItem view property

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am writing a MacOS Menubar app and I want to assign a SwiftUI view as the NSMenuItem view.
Here the current code, but this results in the menu item being hidden.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var firstMenuItem: NSMenuItem?

if let item = firstMenuItem {
    let contentView = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    item.view = contentView.view
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by setting the frame for the view

```swift
if let item = firstMenuItem {
    let contentView = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    contentView.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    item.view = mainView.view
}
```